# mocking authentication spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a respository method annotated with @Secured. I am trying to write a unit test for this method, but my test fails because I need authentication to call the method. The method itself, happens to be the save() method. The error I get when I call the method is:

```
 org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

I cannot test this method because it requires authentication, and  I cannot save a user to authenticate against (I am using hsqldb) because I would need to call this method to save. Any advice on how to unit test a method annotated with @secured or how to mock the authentication.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on what you want to test.

- If you want to test business logic of your application without any security stuff, you can disable security altogether. Assuming that you use `SpringJunit4Runner`, you can put security configuration into separate file and don't include it into `@ContextConfiguration`.
- If you want to test authorization (e.g. correct work of `@Secured` annotations), you can access `SecurityContext` directly, bypassing all authentication-related stuff (in this case you can put authentication configuration into separate file and don't load it as well):

  All you need is to put an appropriate `Authentication` object into [`SecurityContextHolder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html):

  ```
  @Test
  public void myTest() {
      login(...);
      ...
      logout();
  }

  private void login(...) {
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
          new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(...)
      )
  }

  private void logout() {
      SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
  }
  ```
- Finally, if you want to test authentication, you can run the test with the database containing test data.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot do this. My authentication manager is a custom userDetailService which uses my repository to fetch the user from a database. So if I cannot save a user to persistence, then the userDetailsService won't find the user, and thus result in a BadCredentials exception.

Answer (score 5):

a) This is not a unit test, it's an integration test. A unit test would be no problem.

b) I'd try to keep your test setups separated. Why not just deactive spring security in tests where you are not testing security-related features?

c) If all else fails: inject a `JdbcTemplate` object and create the user data manulally in SQL during test setup. See [Support classes for integration testing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testing-support-classes)

Comment: i didn't know it was possible to deactivate the the security at runtime. Do you have a resource you can link me too to see how to deactivate the security?

Comment: @vikashdat Do it the other way: don't activate it. Of course that depends on what kind of test this is. If you're testing against a deployed server that may not be an option.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand..how can I not activate it? Do you mean not running the tests with SpringJunit4Runner? if I do this, I will lose the ability to Autowire components.

Comment: @vikashdat use SpringJunit4Runner, but with a spring context that doesn't know about spring security

Comment: It shouldn't have any security elements, specifically,`<global-method-security>`

Comment: I tried deactivating security using @Profiles and using a child class with Spring Security and another without. The idea was to only load spring security in the web application servlet for production.  This does NOT work right now - Spring Security doesn't play with servlet 3 java config + profiles, you have to keep all the java config in a single class. Spent quite a bit of time scratching my head trying to figure it out - the solution just to create a login()/logout() method for integration tests is better in my opinion anyway - gives you explicit visibility on what is and isn't secured...

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider using an annotation such as `@WithMockUser` to populate test security context with "personas" (test user with specific authorities like 'admin', 'salesman', etc.).

If `@Secured` is on the repo, it must be because specs were stating something like "user must have this grant to query that", and so security should be unit tested too.

If `UsernameAuthenticationToken` (what `@WithMockUser` creates) doesn't meet your needs, then you might choose an other annotation, like [this one](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2-test-addons/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/test/annotations/WithMockAuthentication.java) I wrote, or even write one of your own creating the exact `Authentication` implementation you want.

Libs [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons), sample result extracted from [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2-test-webmvc-addons/src/test/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/tests/webmvc/JwtAuthenticationTokenMessageServiceTests.java)

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(JwtAuthenticationTokenMessageServiceTests.TestConfig.class)
public class JwtAuthenticationTokenMessageServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    private MessageService<JwtAuthenticationToken> messageService;

    @Test
    @WithMockAuthentication(authType = JwtAuthenticationToken.class, authorities = "ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL")
    public void secretWithScopeAuthorizedPersonnelAuthority() {
        assertThat(messageService.getSecret()).isEqualTo("Secret message");
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    @Import({ JwtTestConf.class, JwtAuthenticationTokenServletApp.JwtAuthenticationTokenMessageService.class })
    public static class TestConfig {
    }
```